# Create li elements and <a> tags including href in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a list of li elements with `<a>` tags that include href my code is below

```js
const header_top = document.getElementById("headerTop");
const ul = document.createElement("ul");

links = ['Facebook', 'Youtube', 'Google'];
href = ["https://www.facebook.com/", "https://youtube.com", "https://google.com"]
header_top.appendChild(ul);
links.forEach(rederLi)
function rederLi(link, href) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  const ul_a = document.createElement("a");
  ul_a.textContent = link;
  ul_a.href = href
  li.appendChild(ul_a);
}
```

```html
<header id="headerTop"></header>
```

everything works fine creating them but the href gets the wrong value from the second list. im trying to get something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: well in your case the href is the "index" so change the variable name so it does not conflict with href array and reference the index.... Or create a data structure that is one array of Objects....

Comment: The second parameter of `rederLi` is not the href, that's the index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `function rederLi(link,i)` and `ul_a.href = href[i]`

Comment: You will find the code to be more readable if you created a text block starting with `ul` then creating each `li` as an append text string. Finally, append the `ul` child to `header_top` thus reducing DOM access from 4 to 1.

Comment: You may find [an array of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects) easier to use as they allow you to group related data together. `const companies = [{ name: 'Facebook', link: 'https://www.facebook.com' }, ...]` for example. Then you can loop over the array as you are doing passing in `company` to the function, and then picking out the name and link from the object: `ul_a.textContent = company.name;` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)'s callback function has 3 arguments, `element`, `index`, and `array`.

You were assigning the `index` argument with the name `href` which is misleading. Instead, name it `i` or `index` and access the correct href from your `href` array with `href[index]`.

```js
const header_top = document.getElementById("headerTop");
const ul = document.createElement("ul");
links = ['Facebook', 'Youtube', 'Google'];
href = ["https://www.facebook.com/", "https://youtube.com", "https://google.com"]
header_top.appendChild(ul);
links.forEach(rederLi)

function rederLi(link, index) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  const ul_a = document.createElement("a");
  ul_a.textContent = link;
  ul_a.href = href[index];
  li.appendChild(ul_a);
}
```

```html
<div id="headerTop"></div>
```